# React Router randomly redirect all my request to "/"'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a MERN Stack app at the moment. My routes were working perfectly yesterday but today, for no reason, it doesn't.

When i'm logged in (so when token variable exists), all my requests are redirected to "/".

EDIT: It works with de *Link* component from react-router-dom but not when i type the url in the browser or refresh.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./pages/Auth";
import Book from "./pages/Book";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";

import { AuthContext } from "./shared/context/auth-context";
import { useAuth } from "./shared/hooks/auth-hook";

function App() {
  const { token, login, logout, userId } = useAuth();

  let routes;

  if (token) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/book/shop" exact>
          <Book />
        </Route>

        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth">
          <Auth />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/auth" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn: !!token,
        token: token,
        userId: userId,
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
      }}
    >
      <Router>
        <main>{routes}</main>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any idea about what I'm missing? cause I have no error in console.

Comment: try using exact before the path specified

Comment: Still same behaviour. But I edited my post about the <Link> component vs URL typed in browser.